# Selenium cannot extract text

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, text

I am trying to extract some text from this page

[image]

In particular I want to extract the text between the  tags. I am using Selenium and the following code but even though the object is recognized, the text is an empty string. Below is the code I am using:

`testo = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/span/pre[1]').text`

What do think think it could be the issue?

Comment: You're telling it to start looking from the root, but that stuff is all inside an `<iframe>`.  If you fetch the `<iframe>`, you can search inside of it.  Or maybe fetch the `<span>` directly by class, and get the ``<pre>` inside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text within *`<pre>`* tag is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447)

So to extract the desired text you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#mainFrame")))
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.dettaglio_atto_testo"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='mainFrame']")))
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='dettaglio_atto_testo']/pre"))).text)
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should switch to `iframe`. And then you can use `.getText()` method.

If it doesn't work you can try this: `.getAttribute("innerText")`